# Split string to array filled with null

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to do a loop where i am splitting a String into String[]

sumc is an arraylist, which is a global variable
cind and dbind is String[] and also global variable

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i <= sumc.length - 1 ; i++){

        String local = sumc[i];

        System.out.println(local);

        String[] parts = local.split(":");
        System.out.println(parts[0]);
        System.out.println(parts[1]);
        cind = new String [sumc.length];
        dbind = new String [sumc.length];
        cind[i] = local.split(":")[0];
        dbind[i] = local.split(":")[1];

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cind) + "\t");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dbind) + "\t");
```

So when i do this print, i only get null, null, null except the last one, which is filled with the number

Comment: Post the content of `sumc`. Also it's highly recommended to check the length of `parts` before trying to access it.

Comment: if sumc[i] is an arraylist it must be sumc.get(i);

Comment: `sumc` can't be an arraylist because arraylists don't have a length property. They only have a `size()` method. Also, arraylist can't be used with the array like indexing, they have a `get()` method for that purpose.

Comment: The problem lies within the instantiation of the arrays. Not in `sumc`.

Comment: @AlexR - That is true, but the statement in the question that *sumc is an arraylist* is outright false looking at the code.

Comment: @R.J That is true, but rather a little formal mistake compared to the real problem.

Comment: yep just saw it when i read through the post, sry couldnt delete it. So stupid a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are instantiating `cind` and `dbind` *inside the loop*. This should fix it:

```
cind = new String [sumc.length];
dbind = new String [sumc.length]; 
for (int i = 0 ; i <= sumc.length - 1 ; i++){

    String local = sumc[i];

    System.out.println(local);

    String[] parts = local.split(":");
    System.out.println(parts[0]);
    System.out.println(parts[1]);
    cind[i] = local.split(":")[0];
    dbind[i] = local.split(":")[1];

}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cind) + "\t");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dbind) + "\t");
```

---

A cleaner way of converting your *Array* `sumc` to a table-like structure would be as follows:

```
String[][] data = new String[sumc.length][2];
for (int i = 0; i < sumc.length; i++)
    data[i] = sumc[i].split(":");
```

Access is done via `data[i][0]` and `data[i][1]` respectively.

Comment: yep i just saw my mistake.. but thanks !

Comment: @KlausJoeChristiansen Happy to help. If this answered everything, please mark the question as answered. Else feel free to ask for further explanation.

Comment: Couldnt do it before the time limit hehe :) so had to wait